# How can we get 2 combobox selected items only into 3rd combobox dynamically in java swings?

Tags: java, netbeans, jcombobox

This is what I have done in android ,Here I am having 3 spinners and selecting 
         2 separate spinner items and those items must be dynamically displaying in 
        3rd spinner. and I am trying to do in java swings net beans but I am not 
        getting, how to make please help me. 
         Here in java swings I am using combo boxes instead of spinner.

```
  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> p, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)     {

 switch (p.getId()) {

         case R.id.spinnerPetition:

                i = spinPetition.getSelectedItem().toString();
            spinnerArray1[0] = i;
            Log.d("R", "" + Arrays.toString(spinnerArray1));

            bind();
            break;

        case R.id.spinnerRespondent:

                j = spinRespondent.getSelectedItem().toString();

                spinnerArray1[1] = j;
                Log.d("R", "" + Arrays.toString(spinnerArray1));

                bind();
                break;

            default:
                break;
    }

    private void bind() {

    ArrayAdapter spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerArray1);
    spinAppearingFor.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

}
```

Comment: Seriously, combobox is not the right choice for this...

Comment: ok which is better one to use?

Comment: You're first two comboboxs are fine.  But the third field is simply a concatenation of the first two, you could just use a `JTextField`.  Otherwise you will need to create a compound `for-loop` and seed the third combobox with EVERY possible combination of the other two (and ensure when the selection changes, you combine the two values in the correct way).  This assumes that changing the third combo box will also set the first two ... and that's just generating a large mess ...

Comment: Sir, I dont want the changing in third combo box will set first and second.. if I select first two then they must be dynamically displayed in 3rd combo.

Comment: So I wouldn't use a combobox for the third one, I'd use a `JTextField` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, if the third field will never affect the first two, then it's probably easier to use a `JTextField`, otherwise you will need to build a `ComboBox` which is the conternation of the first two, so that it contains EVERY possible combination...

[image: Combos]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;    import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestFields {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestFields();
    }

    public TestFields() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JComboBox cb1;
        private JComboBox cb2;
        private JTextField field;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            cb1 = new JComboBox(new Object[]{"Banana", "Pear", "Grapes", "Apples"});
            cb2 = new JComboBox(new Object[]{"Monkey", "Elephant", "Dragon", "Gridalo"});
            field = new JTextField(10);
            field.setEditable(false);

            cb1.setSelectedItem(null);
            cb2.setSelectedItem(null);

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

            add(cb1, gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(cb2, gbc);

            gbc.gridx++;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.gridheight = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            add(field, gbc);

            ActionListener handler = new ActionListener() {

                public String getDisplayValue(Object value) {
                    return value == null ? "" : value.toString();
                }

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    field.setText(
                                    getDisplayValue(cb1.getSelectedItem()) + "/" + 
                                    getDisplayValue(cb2.getSelectedItem()));
                }
            };

            cb1.addActionListener(handler);
            cb2.addActionListener(handler);

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I will try this logic in my code.Thank you very much sir. This code helps me ,once again thank you.